# Res.send and if function mix up ..?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

here's my code.
my problem is when I `res.send(message)`, I'm shown the message in entirely, ignoring the last if function with the strict inequality.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const dataBase = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./data/concesionarias.json', 'utf-8'));
module.exports = {
sucursal: function (req, res) {
    let cantSu = 0;
    let message = '*************************************\n\n';
    message += '  \tNUESTRAS SUCURSALES\n\n';
    message += '*************************************\n\n';
    dataBase.forEach(function (sucursal) {
        message += `\t ${sucursal.sucursal} \n`;
        message += '\t-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n';
        message += `\tDIRECCION: ${sucursal.direccion} \n`;
        message += `\tTELEFONO: ${sucursal.telefono} \n`;
        message += '\t-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n';
        cantSu++;
    });
    message += '\n---------------------------\n';
    message += `Total de sucursales: ${cantSu}`;
    message += '\n---------------------------\n';
    res.send(message);
},
detail: function (req, res) {
    let message = '****************************\n\n';
    message += '  \tSUCURSAL\n\n';
    message += '****************************\n\n';
    let x=dataBase.forEach(function (sucursal) {
        if (sucursal.sucursal == req.params.sucursal) {
            message += `\t ${sucursal.sucursal} \n`;
            message += '\t-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n';
            message += `\tDIRECCION: ${sucursal.direccion} \n`;
            message += `\tTELEFONO: ${sucursal.telefono} \n`;
            message += '\t-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n\n';
            message += '****************************\n\n';
            message += '  \tVEHICULOS\n\n';
            message += '****************************\n\n';
            sucursal.autos.forEach(function (auto) {
                message += `MARCA: ${auto.marca} \n`;
                message += `MODELO: ${auto.modelo} \n`;
                message += `YEAR: ${auto.anio} \n`;
                message += '_________________________\n\n';
            });
            message += '\n---------------------------\n';
            message += `TOTAL: ${sucursal.autos.length}`;
            message += '\n---------------------------\n';
            
        }
    });
    if (dataBase.sucursal !== req.params.sucursal){
        message += `Lo siento, por el momento no disponemos de sucursales en ${req.params.sucursal}`;
    }
    res.send(message);
}
}
```

Comment: @Bravo it's ignoring the last if function, `dataBase` is a `JSON.parse`, I'll update the code.

Comment: what I was basically trying to do was if `req.params.location` did not match with any of the locations in `dataBase.location` to `res.send` that specific message instead of actually showing all the locations.

Comment: right now in `detail()`, if I put the correct `req.params.location`, the page displays all the locations and additionally showing me the customized error message that would appear if the correct location wasn't searched. @Bravo